# make tab specific variable via dict data type

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am writing an extension that could detect video request from Coursera page , if detected, then download it when the browser action icon is clicked.

After opened

https://www.coursera.org/learn/human-computer-interaction/lecture/pE6EB/human-computer-interaction

I use `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` to detect the video url,  if detected, assign it to `targetUrl`. Since it's likely to open many Coursera pages at the same time, for example , you can open this link

https://www.coursera.org/learn/human-computer-interaction/lecture/25EPu/the-power-of-prototyping

immediately after you opened the last one, then `targetUrl` is likely to be the  video url of this page instead of last one. To make `targetUrl` specific to each Coursera page , I am going to use the dictionary data type to store the  tab specific variable , the key should be a tab unique property, the value is the video url at corresponding  page.

The difficulty I am facing is that I don't know how and when to create the key, any help ?

It seems appropriate to create the key after `targetUrl` is assigned value , I use `chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function callback)` to get the tab property there (the commented code in `background.js`), but I just got undefined object, anyone can explain why ?

Following is the code

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2, 
    "name": "Coursera", 
    "version": "1.0", 
    "minimum_chrome_version": "31", 
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "video-128.png", 
        "default_title": "Click here!"
    }, 
    "description": "I can't has cheezburger!", 
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab", 
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/*", 
        "https://*/*", 
        "cookies", 
        "storage", 
        "management", 
        "downloads", 
        "webRequest", 
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ], 
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

background.js

```
var tabId;
var tabId2targetUrl={};
var targetUrl;

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    targetUrl = details.url;

    // chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {console.log(tab.title);});
    // tabId2targetUrl[tabId]=targetUrl;

    console.log(targetUrl);  
},
{
    urls: ["https://*.cloudfront.net/*index.webm*", "https://*.cloudfront.net/*index.mp4*", "http://*/*.aac","http://v.stu.126.net/mooc-video/nos/flv/*",  "http://*/*.mp4"]
});


chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    // targetUrl=tabId2targetUrl[tabId];

    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = targetUrl;
    var pathname= parser.pathname;
    fileNameExt =pathname.substr(pathname.lastIndexOf('.') );

    chrome.downloads.download({
        url: targetUrl,
        filename: tab.title.split(' - ')[0] + fileNameExt
    },
    function(downloadId) {
        console.log('downloadId '+downloadId);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`tabId` should serve your purpose, and it is actually provided by `webRequest`/`browserAction` events.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
  targetUrl = details.url;
  tabId2targetUrl[details.tabId]=targetUrl;
},
{
    urls: ["https://*.cloudfront.net/*index.webm*", "https://*.cloudfront.net/*index.mp4*", "http://*/*.aac","http://v.stu.126.net/mooc-video/nos/flv/*",  "http://*/*.mp4"]
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  targetUrl=tabId2targetUrl[tab.id];
  /* ... */
});
```

Do note: you may want to clear the dictionary entry when the tab navigates away.

---

It might be much easier in your case to use a content script to extract the URL from the page on demand. No need to maintain dictionaries in this case.

Alternatively, you could (and should!) use a [Page Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction), showing it after the URL was detected. It will automatically clear on navigating away (unless there's a `pushState`-based transition, IIRC)

> **Do** use page actions for features that make sense for only a few pages.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help ! 1) I did make a content script version , and you can download it here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yEgmz6VGdzRVUtZGtMdTBTWWc/view  The issue with the  content script version is that there is some delay after browserAction was clicked and before the download begin, any ideas on reducing the delay ? 2) I still made a webRequest version using a Page Action ,download it here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yEgmz6VGdzS2Z3NE9sLUtzeGs/view  but I didn't clear the dictionary entry , will it automatically clear on navigating away ? why ? what is pushState ?

Comment: 1) I will not even look at your externally-hosted files; it's your work to isolate relevant sections, not mine, for a good question 2) You should not ask follow-up questions in comments as a general rule; make a new question.

Comment: `pushState` is history manipulation; when the address changes but no actual navigation takes place; youtube switching to related videos is an example.

Comment: what do you mean by "navigating away"?

Comment: @iMath When the page (document/URL) changes.

Comment: both document and URL changes or either ?